# Microsoft Word - Align lines for each outline level

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

How can each multi-level list item be indented more than the previous, but individual lines under a given multi-level list item be horizontally aligned the same. For instance, `1.1.1.1.1.1` is indented more than `1.1.1.1.1`as desired, but the first line under `1.1.1.1.1.1` starts further to the right than following lines. Can this be applied globally to all multi-level list items?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting "Aligned at" and "Text indent at" to the same value?

Comment: @DavidPostill  Yes, 1.25 is for the start of the numbers and 1.9 is for the text, so to make it appear aligned, one would need to change 1.9 to about 3".  The same trial and error approach can be performed on all lines.  But really?  Don't other people like text aligned?  There is got to be a better way.